# Magento 1.9: Missing translation of the minicart "remove item" pop-up buttons?

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, rwd

The pop-up window which is shown when clicking "Remove item" in the mini-cart ("Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?") shows two buttons "OK" and "Cancel". In my localized version these buttons remain untranslated. Mage_Checkout.csv does not contain a translation for "OK" and the one for "Cancel" is obviously not used. Where/How can I add a translation for these buttons? I am using the RWD theme.

[image: "Remove item" pop-up window with untranslated buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is the browsers default confirm dialog, so it can't be translated via `CSV`.

Related posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694133/localization-for-javascript-confirmation-buttons
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901745/do-browsers-localize-the-ok-and-cancel-buttons-of-the-javascript-confirm-popup

Comment: I can confirm the answer. The buttons are shown localized on a non-English computer/OS. Thanks a lot!!